# D-Link DGS-1005A: What does an orange light mean and why is it only orange for one port?

Tags: networking, router, switch, internet-speed

I use a D-Link DGS-1005A unmanaged switch that sits between my main router and my personal machine. There are also 2 other machines that connect to this switch. My machine is on the 1st port and the other two machines are on the 2nd and 3rd port while the main router connects via the 5th port.

The other two machines that connect to the 2nd and 3rd port have a green blinking light but  the light under port 1 which is the one I connect to has an amber/orange blinking light and I cannot find any information that explains what does that mean.

Occasionally I get a very big drop in download speed on my machine but when I do a speed-test using my phone that connects via Wi-Fi to the main router has no issues and I suspect that the orange light might have something to do with this.

The only [information](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/692370/D-Link-Dgs-1005d.html?page=11) I've found so far regarding the orange light is for DGS-1005D and is the following:

> Link/Act/Speed:
> When connected to a 1000Mbps device, this LED indicator light is green when the port is connected to adevice and will blink as data is transmitted or received.When connected to a 10/100Mbps device, this LED indicator light is amber when the port is connected to adevice and will blink as data is transmitted or received.

Comment: It's right there in your quote. Orange means it's only connecting at 100Base-T. First suspect is always the cable. Try one of the others you know works at 1000Base-T.

Answer (score 0):

> **When connected to a 10/100Mbps device, this LED indicator light is amber** when the port is connected to adevice and will blink as data is transmitted or received.